# How to rename a file in C#

Tags: asp.net, xml

Consider:

```
strPath= c:\images\gallery\add.gif
```

I need to rename this file from `add.gif` to `thumb1.gid`, and I  should  write one command method, whatever the file name. We need to
replace that name with this like below.

```
string strfilename = **"thumb"**
```

****Result thum.gif**

`strPath= c:\images\gallery\thum.gif` **

Comment: why you posting same question again and again?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673018/how-to-retrive-an-value-from-xml-for-a-particluar-node-and-again/1673161#1673161

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672753/iterate-through-an-xml-file-for-a-selected-node

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have several problems, looking up the value in the XML file, and renaming the file.

To look up the number corresponding to Gallery2 or whatever, I would recommend having a look at Stack Overflow question *[How to implement a simple XPath lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169398)* which explains how to look up  nodes/values in an XML file.

To rename a file in .NET, use something like this:

```
using System.IO;

FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("c:\\images\\gallery\\add.gif");
if (fi.Exists)
{
    fi.MoveTo("c:\\images\\gallery\\thumb3.gif");
}
```

Of course, you would use string variables instead of string literals for the paths.

That should give you enough information to piece it together and solve your particular lookup-rename problem.

Comment: Don't use File.Exists() like that.  Just wrap it in a try/catch instead.  You have to use the try/catch anyway, because the file system is volatile, and things could change between when you check .Exists() and when you call .MoveTo(), so you may as well just skip the Exists() check.

Answer (score 2):

I created a utility method to help encapsulate how to rename a file.

```
    public class FileUtilities
    {
        public static void RenameFile(string oldFilenameWithPathWithExtension, string newFilenameWithoutPathWithExtension)
        {
            try 
            {
                string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(oldFilenameWithPathWithExtension);
                if (directoryPath == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Directory not found in given path value:{oldFilenameWithPathWithExtension}");
                }

                var newFilenameWithPath = Path.Combine(directoryPath, newFilenameWithoutPathWithExtension);
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(oldFilenameWithPathWithExtension);
                fileInfo.MoveTo(newFilenameWithPath);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Boiler plate exception handling
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

I omitted several other file system checks that could optionally be done, but as @JoelCoehoorn pointed out in a comment on this page, the File System is Volatile, so wrapping it in a try-catch may be all that is necessary.

With that class in your library, now you can simply call:

```
            var fullFilename = @"C:\images\gallery\add.gif";
            var newFilename = "Thumb.gif";
            FileHelper.RenameFile(fullFilename,newFilename);
```